# eliminate render blocking resourcejacascript with .pagespeed extension

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am getting error **Eliminate Render Blocking Resource** in file, 
it is having the extension of .pagespeed.*js

/media/js/fe2e6f53276726439b1fac7296dd6414.js.pagespeed.jm.nywy_6kRdV.js

I installed google speed module for apache server

how can i resolve this

Comment: do you have varnish?